# What is the syntax for putting a nofollow attribute into a javascript file

Tags: google, javascript, nofollow

[Matt Cutts states in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LW3pjQeCqqk):

> It turns out that as we are executing JavaScript, we do look at the attributes.  So you can actually use Javascript and put, like, a nofollow attribute on individual URLs.

I'm not clear to me what the syntax for that would be.  How would I put a nofollow on a  link in a variable like this?

```
var mylink = "http://example.com/";
```

or if it in AJAX like this?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/path/ajax-handler/' + method,
    success: function(data) ...
```

Answer (score 4):

What he is referring to is the HTML markup of the page. The nofollow keyword goes into a *rel* attribute on a tag, usually an `<a>` tag with an *href* like so: `<a href="/link" rel="nofollow">link</a>`. So he is suggesting that if you don't want search engines parsing through your javascript and looking for links you can do this:

```
<script rel="nofollow" src="/js/code.js"></script>
```

Comment: I hadn't considered that.  That would be decidedly less useful than I was hoping.

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute "rel" in `<script>`, therefore the following code will produce a validation error in your CSS:

```
<script rel="nofollow" src="/js/code.js"></script>
```

Does Google follow JavaScript links? Yes.
http://www.adherewebdesign.com/experiment/results/

Possible solution:
Edit robots.txt to include the following line:

```
User-agent: * Disallow: http://offending-java-url.com
```

This will stop all bots from following the java link.

Also,
You can verify your CSS validation here:
http://validator.w3.org/